# I can still see faces in baked normals

Tags: texture-baking, normals, baking, normal-map

I am trying to create a horse. I sculpted a high poly version, created a remeshed version with applied shrinkwrap modifier. Now I should bake the normals, but the baked normals have sharp edges even though I have smooth shading enabled. What causes the problem?

[image]

[image: Normal map]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For baking, set *Cage Extrusion* to `0.05 m` and *Max Ray Distance* to `0 m` (unlimited). This reduces the glitches/artefacts.

For the shader, set *Color Space* of the *Image Texture* node to `Non Color`. Increase the *Strength* value of the *Normal Map* node to `1.0` if you like. It was 0.5 in your blend file.

<sup>(The *Metallic* in the screenshot is just to highlight the details.)</sup>

[image: low-poly horse]